# Statement.setQueryTimeout does not throw an Exception (SQL SERVER)

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, timeout

I'm using JDBC Microsoft SQL SERVER DRIVER and when i set query timeout, the driver return the query results until that moment.

But the driver does not throw a *SQLTimeoutException* (see javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int))
How can i solve this problem? I need to know when occurs a timeout...

Sample code, where we can see the problem:

```
try {
    Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getNewConnection();
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    st.setQueryTimeout(10);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(" ... some query takes long time ... ");
    while (rs.next()) {
        // ...
    // actions with result
        // ...
    }

} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I believe the query returns a partial result. Because is possible to scroll through the resultset and print the result ...

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: What does it do if it doesn't throw an exception?  Does it return an empty ResultSet?

Comment: I believe the query returns a partial result. Because is possible to scroll through the resultset and print the result ...